# iOS: UITextField with SecureEntry sometimes highlights yellow color with "Strong Password" text, and then keyboard gets stuck

Tags: ios, swift, uitextfield, ios13, ios13.6

UITextField with SecureEntry sometimes highlights yellow color with "**Strong Password**" text, and then the keyboard gets stuck

I haven't able to identify why this issue occurs, Sometimes I am facing this issue when I start typing in UITextField then get a **yellow color background** with a "**Strong Password**" text on the right side, and something cut off on the left. I can still tap the UITextField and "Type" but the value does not change within the TextField.

[image]

I am using xCode 11.6 and facing this issue with iOS 13.6 simulator.

Answer (score 2):

As I've discovered this issue while developing a `React Native` app, I thought it was a bug on the `JavaScript` level. But it turned out this is an issue on the `iOS` level.

As far as I have searched, I don't think that there's currently a fix for this bug, but there is a workaround. As stated [in this comment](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/21911#issuecomment-730214540): all you have to do is change the `textContentType` property of the `UITextField` to `oneTimeCode`.

You can do it through Xcode, by selecting the `UITextField`, then switching over to the attributes inspector and selecting the `Content Type` property to be `One Time Code`:

[image: One time code UITextField Content Type property]

Or directly through code.

Swift:

```
let textField = UITextField()
textField.textContentType = .oneTimeCode
```

Objective C:

```
UITextField *textField = [UITextField new];
textField.textContentType = UITextContentTypeOneTimeCode;
```

Comment: It's working at my end. Thanks!

Comment: This will stop iOS from suggesting passwords to the user. And it won't attempt to auto fill if the user has a password manager installed.

Comment: doesn't work at all

Answer (score -2):

For me, it also helped to change the Content Type for the text field to One Time Code in the registration view. Interestingly that in the same project, I have a similar view "Login view" with a similar text field and there I do not see this issue.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).